# Export CSV file to Excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, csv

I have some code for sending a data result to the user as CSV.
This works fine with Excel 2013 but in Excel 2007, it won't split into columns, but rather as data inserted into only one column.

Is there a way of telling Excel how to split the text (it's separated by ; ) ?
Here is my code:

```
    public async Task ExcelResultList(int id)
    {
        var asString = await Resolver.Resolve<IHandoutManager>().GetResultListAsStringAsync(id);
        var handout = await Resolver.Resolve<IHandoutManager>().GetHandout(id);

        var filename = string.Format("{0} registrations - {1:yyyy-MM-dd}.csv", handout.Name, DateTime.Now);
        var contenttype = "application/csv";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = contenttype;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);            
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode; 
        Response.Write(asString);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: .csv stands for 'comma-separated value', and in the older versions of Excel, including Excel 2010, the separator had to actually be a comma "," for automatic column detection to work.  The most straightforward fix would be to replace your ";" with ",".

Comment: The difference is actually based on the regional settings of the computer the "," is not always the list separator for all languages/countries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure that you are using the correct ListSeparator ("," or ";") use this

> System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator

But since you only have access to the server side, then you can include this javascript in any of your pages,

```
function getListSeparator() {
    var list = ['a', 'b'], str;
    if (list.toLocaleString) {
        str = list.toLocaleString();
        if (str.indexOf(';') > 0 && str.indexOf(',') == -1) {
            return ';';
        }
    }
    return ',';
}
```

The key is in the **toLocaleString** method that uses the system list separator of the client side

You could use JavaScript to get the list separator and set it in a cookie which you could then detect from your server to generate the file as needed

And also have you try changing the **contenttype** to

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

or

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Comment: I have only control of the web server and not the clients. By using the ListSeparator, will that have any effect on the clients reading the CSV ?

Comment: @thomas I have included a javascript aproach to my response so that is modified in the server side but is executed on the client to detect the list separator